# PHP check postal code

Tags: php, html, css, regex

I need to verify the postal code inserted in a text box and stored in a variable: "$code".

iIf the format is like this: `XXXX – XXX` it's valid. If not, it's invalid (the X's are numbers).

Someone told me to make a regex like this one but applied to my needs:

```
$regex = "/^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$/";
```

Not only do I not know how to make that, but I also don't know what to do after.

Do you guys have any idea on how to solve my problem?

Comment: i don't know why you put this `[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]` in your regex.

Comment: it's just a example of a regex they gave to guide myself, but i cant really understand to be honest

Comment: if you want numbers then your regex is totally wrong.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it's an example that has been provided by "someone" but that has nothing to do with what he wishes to do ;)

Comment: does the postal code must contain spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like :

```
/^[0-9]{4}\s-\s[0-9]{3}$/
```

Or :

```
/^\d{4}\s-\s\d{3}$/
```

EDIT : If you have 0 or more space between the `-` and the digits :

```
/^\d{4}\s*-\s*\d{3}$/
```

If you have 0 or only one space between the `-` and the digits :

```
/^\d{4}\s?-\s?\d{3}$/
```

If you haven't any spaces between the `-` and the digits :

```
/^\d{4}-\d{3}$/
```

Comment: it's better to use `\s*` rather than `\s`

Comment: im trying that in this site: http://regex101.com/#pcre

and it doesnt work, i introduced some postal codes like: 1111-111 or 2561-122 and it doesnt match so in the PHP it always says invalid

Comment: @AvinashRaj : I'm not sure there's potentially 0 or more spaces, it's the author who have to define such rules or not.

Comment: @user3807727 : because your first example hasn't exactly the same pattern, i'll update my answer ;)

Comment: i'm sorry im messing up so much, i just have no experience working with this stuff

Comment: @user3807727 if you use `^` and `$` in your pattern then you must set multiline `m` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Well, some more insight into the postal codes you'd like to validate would help. But here is some general advise.

Regular expressions are extremely powerful but also complicated, hard to maintain and slow compared to many other language features.

If you need to validate the length of a number, simply cast it to a string and calculate the length.

```
<?php

$len = strlen((string) $number);
if ($len < 3 || $len > 4) {
    // invalid
}
```

If you need to validate a number, use [PHP's built-in filter functions](http://php.net/ref.filter).

```
<?php

$valid = filter_var(FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
  "options" => array(
    "max" => 9999,
    "min" => 100,
  ),
));
```

A regular expression might come in handy if you need the separator character.

```
<?php

$valid = (boolean) preg_match("/^\d{4}\s(-|–|—)\s\d{3}$/");
```

Or combine regular expression with filter functions.

```
<?php

$valid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "postalcode", FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array(
  "options" => array(
    "regexp" => "/^\d{4}\s(-|–|—)\s\d{3}$/",
  ),
));
```

Although you could validate it with pure PHP as well, just in case the regular expression thingy is still to complicated for you.

There are many great websites out there to learn regular expressions or to test them. A personal favorite (not affiliated with) of mine is [regex101](http://regex101.com/).